# How do say toilet paper in Chinese?

Tags: translation, usage

Was validating some Google translations and came upon this question:

rolling papers:
1. 廁所用紙
2. 捲菸紙

How do say toilet paper in Chinese? The more technical term for the commonly used toilet paper is 抽取式衛生紙, what about the Western toilet paper rolls?

Comment: How about 卷筒式卫生纸？

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for, was hard to think of what it was called until I saw your comment.

Comment: I also thought about 5 minutes. In most cases just `卫生纸` is fine for toilet paper. And see little of other types of toilet paper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Hong Kong "Toilet paper" is simply called 廁紙.

Before the modern toilet paper,  people were using 草紙(rough straw paper) for toilet paper.

As for a roll of toilet paper , it is still called " 廁紙 " ( with classifier if needed. For example  一卷廁紙 ) and the more technical term would be 卷裝廁紙

For tissues in a box, we call it 紙巾 (with classifier if needed. For example 一盒紙巾)and the more technical term would be 盒裝紙巾

*衛生紙 is another name for 廁紙 or 紙巾.

Comment: thanks for additional information. Im a translator and often have to translate more technical stuff. A common problem I have is "if you don't use it, you'll forget it," and that's when I decided to ask others for help.

Comment: I'll add in some other examples for those in taiwan
衛生紙功能分類 types of tissues    
擦手紙 / 擦手巾 / 餐巾紙 napkin    
廚房紙巾 paper towels    
盒裝面紙 / 面紙  facial tissue / Kleenex     
抽取衛生紙 / 捲筒衛生紙 toilet paper   
三層抽取式 3 layer toilet paper (For those who don't like the toilet paper ripping if you just had a watery one)

Answer (score 2):

In mainland China, we use 衛生紙、廁紙、手紙. Paper rolls we call them 卷紙. The 抽取式衛生紙 is called as 紙抽.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for reposting this answer, first time using the comment section and didn't like how the comment was formatted)

For those wanting to learn Chinese
I'll add in some other examples for those in taiwan

衛生紙功能分類 types of tissues
擦手紙 / 擦手巾 / 餐巾紙 napkin
廚房紙巾 paper towels
盒裝面紙 / 面紙  facial tissue / Kleenex
抽取衛生紙 / 捲筒衛生紙 toilet paper 
三層抽取式 3 layer toilet paper (For those who don't like the toilet paper ripping if you just had a watery one)

Answer (score 0):

手纸:this could be more casually
卫生纸:more formally

ask ur mother to bring back some手纸

Our 卫生纸  is the best production you ll never seen,A CEO said

Answer (score 0):

we  usually say `卫生纸` in china,`卫生纸`is the Simplified Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

“餐巾纸” in restaurant, or means “napkin”

“面巾纸” or “手帕纸”  for papers like a handkerchief

“厕纸” for toilet paper，but it is not used in common.

Whatever the paper is, saying “卫生纸” is always right. For the daily use soft paper，we do not distinguish that much.

And we will never say “厕所用纸”“抽式卫生纸”.

Answer (score -1):

usually, in my family,we just say "卷筒纸" or "手纸".